# Table Border remains open

Tags: tables, border

I'm struggling with properly closing the border around the following table (column 2 & 3). I'm relatively inexperienced with LateX and my searches yielded little result.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
\hline 
   & Prozess & Thread \\
\hline
Die Zuteilung der CPU (f"ur das Scheduling erfolgt)  \\ 
an ... 
& \multirow{-2}{*} {x}  & \multirow{-2}{*}{-} \\
\hline
Der Adressraum ist zugeordnet an ... & x & x \\
\hline
CPU-Registersatz wird individuell/privat verwendet \\ 
von ...  & \multirow{-2}{*} x  & \multirow{-2}{*} x \\
\hline
Betriebsmittel (z.B. Dateien u."A.) werden vom BS zu- \\ geordnet an      
... & \multirow{-2}{*}{x}  &  \multirow{-2}{*}{x} \\
\hline
F"ur die Programmierung von Anwendungen muss die- \\ ses BS API-   
Funktionen anbieten zum Erzeugen/Beenden von ... & \multirow{-2}{*} x 
& \multirow{-2}{*} x \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Prozesse \& Threads }\label{table_exp}
\end{table}
```

Comment: What does `\Hilfe` do? Please complete your code with the packages and definitions required to run it.

Comment: `Die Zuteilung der CPU (f"ur das Scheduling erfolgt)  \\ ` only has one cell as there is no second or third cell you do not get their line, you need `Die Zuteilung der CPU (f"ur das Scheduling erfolgt) && \\ `

Comment: "Hilfe" got inserted due to Auto-Grammar correction on MacOS. My bad on that one. Otherwise, what David suggested works. Can someone explain to me why I need {-2} argument in multirow command instead of 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually not need the `multirow` package ... Instead complication with it and manual (in your case wrong) breaking lines you should use a column type like `p{...}` or `m{...}` from package `array` or `X` from package `tabularx` etc.

In case of use `tabularx` and desired vertical centering of contents in right columns you need to redefine `X` column type. See code below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|c|c|}
\hline
        & Prozess   &   Thread              \\
\hline
Die Zuteilung der CPU (für das Scheduling erfolgt) an ... 
an ...  &   x       &   -                   \\
\hline
Der Adressraum ist zugeordnet an ... 
        &   x       &   x                   \\
\hline
CPU-Registersatz wird individuell/privat verwendet von ...
        &   x       &   x                   \\
\hline
Betriebsmittel (z.B. Dateien u."A.) werden vom BS zugeordnet an
... 
        &   x       &   x                   \\
\hline
Für die Programmierung von Anwendungen muss dieses BS API-
Funktionen anbieten zum Erzeugen/Beenden von ... 
        &   x       &   x                   \\
\hline
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{Prozesse \& Threads }\label{table_exp}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: That looks really quite good. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the design of your table, I would like to suggest you get rid of all vertical lines and, while you're at it, most horizontal lines as well. Use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package -- here: `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` -- for the three remaining lines. I'm pretty sure your readers will appreciate the resulting "open" look of the table. A side-benefit of adopting this approach is that there's no need to figure out why some vertical lines are showing gaps...

Do also consider using a `tabularx` environment and letting LaTeX find the best line breaks in the first column.

Optional: For a slightly snazzy look, think about replacing the `x` and `-` symbols in columns 2 and 3 with `$\times$` and `$-$`, respectively. :-) And, replace the word/separating `/` ("slash") symbols with `\slash`; that way, line breaks at those slash symbols will be permitted.

[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Lcc@{}}
\toprule 
 & Prozess & Thread \\
\midrule
Die Zuteilung der CPU (f"ur das Scheduling erfolgt) an~\dots 
& $\times$  & $-$ \\
\addlinespace
Der Adressraum ist zugeordnet an~\dots & $\times$ & $\times$ \\
\addlinespace
CPU-Registersatz wird individuell\slash privat verwendet von~\dots  & $\times$  & $\times$ \\
\addlinespace
Betriebsmittel (z.B. Dateien u."A.) werden vom BS zugeordnet an~\dots  & $\times$  & $\times$ \\
\addlinespace
F"ur die Programmierung von Anwendungen muss dieses BS API-Funktionen anbieten zum Erzeugen\slash Beenden von~\dots & $\times$ &  $\times$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Prozesse \& Threads }\label{table_exp}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```